# LZO for cloudera cdh3u2

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

With some bewilderment I read [cloudera's blog post on lzo on cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/06/parallel-lzo-splittable-compression-for-hadoop/). Due to some licensing bs, lzo compression is not part of standard hadoop, ok. But what's stopping cloudera from making it part of their distribution? Or has this happened?

In short, how do you make lzo compression happen on cloudera cdh3u2?

Answer (score 1):

> But what's stopping cloudera from making it part of their distribution? Or has this happened?

Both Apache Hadoop and Cloudera CDH are [released](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Hadoop+FAQ) under the same Apache Public License version 2, so I don't think LZO can be included in CDH due to the GPL restrictions.

> In short, how do you make lzo compression happen on cloudera cdh3u2?

I haven't tried them out, but here are the [instructions](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/) for using LZO with Hadoop.

Comment: I know those instructions, I pointed to them in the question. I was wondering if they aren't outdated.

Comment: Best thing when not sure of something is try them out - that's what I usually do - if it doesn't then I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard very positive feedback from clients who are using Snappy, rather than LZO - Cloudera has an article about this topic on their [blog](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/09/snappy-and-hadoop/).

Comment: Snappy files are not splittable.